# How to sum columns in R according to categories in 2 different groups

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following dataset imported from excel via "readxl::read_excel" command:

```
Municipality    Production  Type
Atima           690         Reverification
Atima           120         Reverification
Atima           220         Reverification
Comayagua       153         Initial
Comayagua       193         Initial
Comayagua       138         Initial
Comayagua       307         Reverification
Copán           179         Initial
Copán           100         Initial
Copán           236         Reverification
Copán           141         Reverification
Danlí            56         Reverification
...
```

Subsequently used the code below as the data was tbl_df.

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

I want to sort the data by Type and add up the Production to get the total Production for each Municipality:

```
Municipality    Production  Type
Atima           1030        Reverification
Comayagua       484         Initial
Comayagua       307         Reverification
Copán           279         Initial
Copán           377         Reverification
Danlí            56         Reverification
```

I looked up in other post, but I was only able to find how to sum it up for one categorical variable. How could I do this in R? Or should I first do it in excel and then import the table?

I'm working in Rstudio Version 0.99.441, in Windows 7.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the aggregating functions

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[,list(Production=sum(Production)) , .(Municipality,Type)]
 #    Municipality           Type Production
 # 1:        Atima Reverification       1030
 # 2:    Comayagua        Initial        484
 # 3:    Comayagua Reverification        307
 # 4:        Copán        Initial        279
 # 5:        Copán Reverification        377
 # 6:        Danlí Reverification         56
```

or

```
res <- aggregate(Production~., df1, FUN=sum)
res1 <- res[with(res, order(Municipality,-Production)),]
row.names(res1) <- NULL
res1
#  Municipality           Type Production
#1        Atima Reverification       1030
#2    Comayagua        Initial        484
#3    Comayagua Reverification        307
#4        Copán Reverification        377
#5        Copán        Initial        279
#6        Danlí Reverification         56
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Municipality = c("Atima", "Atima", "Atima", "Comayagua", 
"Comayagua", "Comayagua", "Comayagua", "Copán", "Copán", "Copán", 
"Copán", "Danlí"), Production = c(690L, 120L, 220L, 153L, 193L, 
138L, 307L, 179L, 100L, 236L, 141L, 56L), Type = c("Reverification", 
"Reverification", "Reverification", "Initial", "Initial", "Initial", 
"Reverification", "Initial", "Initial", "Reverification", "Reverification", 
"Reverification")), .Names = c("Municipality", "Production", 
"Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, for the 1st method it gives me the following result:

    Municipio                 Type Production1:             Atima         Initial unit   511554.5
 2:          Guaimaca         Initial unit   511554.5
 3:         Las Lajas         Initial unit   511554.5
 4:      San Jeronimo         Initial unit   511554.5
 5:       La Libertad         Initial unit   511554.5
 6:             Otoro         Initial unit   511554.5

Comment: @JorgeAnariba  I am getting the output as you showed in your post.

Comment: I'll try again. In the 2nd method, I get 2 Production columns mirror of one another. It shows a sum but it seems that it isn't the total sum:

    Municipality     Production        Type                     Production
    Atima              1584.44444       Reverification       1584.44444
    Atima              76.222               Reverification       76.222

I guess there's something wrong with my dataset.

Comment: @JorgeAnariba Are you using the same data as you showed in your post

Comment: Hi akrun, should I write the code like this:  
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[,list(df1$Production=sum(df1$Production)) , .(df1$Municipality,df1$Type)]
?

Comment: @JogeAnariba No, you don't have to do that.   It's not a data.table syntax.

Comment: @JorgeAnariba  I updated the post with the data I used and the output I got.  Can you test with the data I showed

Comment: both methods worked well with the data structured as you did, but when I tried method 1 for my whole dataset I get the following message: Error in `[.tbl_df`(setDT(df1), , list(Production = sum(Production)),  : 
  could not find function "." And when I try for method 2, the same problem as before appears in which I get 2 Production columns mirror of one another.

Comment: @JorgeAnariba Can you try this on a plain `data.frame` as the data you have is `tbl_df`. Try `honcafe2 <- as.data.frame(honcafe2)`  Also, you have double `,` in the code.  Can you check for that typo?

Comment: @JorgeAnariba Can you provide a subset of dataset that shows this kind of problems.  It is better to use `dput` to get the output (like the structure output I used in my post)

Comment: i'll redo my dataset and try again.

Comment: I redid my dataset, used honcafe2 <- as.data.frame(honcafe2), and now both methods worked perfectly. Is it possible to add this result column to the dataset?

Comment: @JorgeAnariba If you need this as a new column in the original dataset, `setDT(df1)[,  SumProduction1 := sum(Production) , .(Municipality,Type)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Municipality, Type) %>%
  summarize(Production=sum(Production))
```

Comment: Hi MattV, i'm getting the following message:
The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    between, last

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.1.3

Comment: This just means that the packages have overlapping functions (both dplyr and data.table have a function called 'last'). The package that is loaded last takes precedence, so calling 'last' now means you're calling the one from dplyr rather than the one in data.table.

Comment: I tried again, it worked now, but it only displays the first 10 rows. Is it possible to add this result column to the dataset?

Comment: You have two options here, create a new data.frame by entering summarized.df <- df %>% ...; Alternatively, overwrite df and add the aggregates as columns by using df <- df %>% group_by(..) %>% mutate(...). If you replace summarize by mutate it will return the original data.frame with the new aggregate column. Be sure to change its name (otherwise we have two columns named 'Production')!